# Rewiring actions of parent to a child viewmodel

Tags: caliburn.micro

So here's my screnario. I have a toolbar at the top (office style), with buttons. This is hosted in a shell. Some of those buttons are applicable only to certain child view models as they get loaded. Ideally what I would like to happen is have the buttons action.target repositioned to child view model as it gets created (I kind of got this working by settings `Action.Target="ActiveItem"` on them. This doesn't solve the problem fully though:

a) When the child viewmodel is closed and there is no active item, I want them to reposition to Shell as the target so they can be set to "default" state.
b) I noticed that when child viewmodel is closed and the shell being the conductor has it ActiveItem=null, the hooks from the action are still bound to the living instance of the last viewmodel, so doesn't looks like it got disposed of. Memory leak?

Any suggestions how to implement this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding a property to your `ShellViewModel` which points to the action target and updating it when stuff gets activated/deactivated:

e.g.

```
public class ShellViewModel
{
    public object ActionTarget
    {
        get { return _actionTarget; }
        set 
        { 
            _actionTarget = value; 
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ActionTarget); 
        }
    }

    // Then when the active item changes just update the target:
    public override NotifyOfPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        if(propertyName == "ActiveItem") 
        {
            if(ActiveItem == null) ActionTarget = this;
            else ActionTarget = ActiveItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Now bind to that:

```
<SomeMenu cal:Action.Target="{Binding ActionTarget}" />
```

Not sure if that will work or not but I'm sure I've done something similar in the past. (You may also have to explicitly call NPC on your actions before they will update after you have changed `ActiveItem`)

Comment: That worked. The only difference is instead of overriding NotifyOfPropertyChange I stuck the if into OnActionationProcessed inside the conductor